# bloom ignore rpm

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to ignore RPM releases and only trigger Ubuntu targets?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199750/bloom-ignore-rpm/) by [weisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1163/weisshardt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remove the action to generate RPM's from the `tracks.yaml` file, for example these lines:

https://github.com/wjwwood/serial-release/blob/master/tracks.yaml#L70-71

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0